# Remove all but URL form code

Tags: notepad++, notepad

So i have a code with bunch of links. What i want is to remove everything that is not an URL. For example currently it looks something like this:

"id":"2","name":"name","orderBy":"1","version":"2","files":"http://domain.com/library/library_folder/library/files.zip"

What I want as a result is I want to take those links

http://domain.com/library/library_folder/library/files.zip

Comment: This is a job for Regex.  See [regex-weburl](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294)

Comment: How to.
I do not really understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*(http\S+)".*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Make sure to check `Regular expression`